# Convert text link to HTML with context considered

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to convert links such as http://google.com/ to HTML, however if they're already in an HTML link, either in the href="" or in the text for the link, I don't want to convert them.

I found this in another question:

```
preg_replace('@(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
```

However if I have something such as:

```
<a href="http://google.com/">http://google.com/</a>
```

already in the target text in question, it will create two links within that HTML. I can't seem to figure out the pattern for knowing if it's before /a or inside " ".

Comment: [DON'T DO IT MAN!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: bbpress does it, except looking through their spaghetti code, I can't seem to figure out how it's doing it.

Comment: Context-awareness isn't simple, but you can likely get away with the minimum lookaround. Precede your regex with `(?<!href="|src="|">)` a negative assertion to exclude the main culprits. (Another common approach is to *normalize* the input text by removing already HTMLified URLs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on mario's comment to my original post:

```
preg_replace('@(?<!href="|src="|">)(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Works perfectly for replacing bbpress's unknown pasta salad.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regular expressions for (X)HTML parsing. Use DOM instead!
The [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) `//text()[not(ancestor::a) and contains(., 'http://')][1]` should find the first text node containing at least one HTTP URL that is not itself contained in an anchor tag. You may naively replace the text node with a text node containing preceding text, an anchor element node containing href attribute and href text node, and a text node containing remaining text. Do that until you find no more text nodes matching the XPath.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a sample XSLT to make a transformation?

Comment: I never did any XSLT. I would implement it with a while loop because text nodes containing more than one URL need to be processed more than once.