# Using PHP pregreplace to turn specific words in my text into links if they aren't already a link and add anchor text

Tags: php

Similar to what's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129283/convert-text-link-to-html-with-context-considered) and many other places on stackoverflow, but with a twist.

Say I have the sentence "I like brown dogs." on my page. I want to process this text before it's output and look for the word brown. If brown is already part of a link (wrapped in an A tag) then do nothing. However if it is not in a link, use my pre-defined code as a replacement.

My code would be something like this:

```
<a href="/brown" title="Looking for the color brown?">brown</a>
```

It would be best if the original case of the word didn't change either.

I'd like this to be an array I can specify, such as:

```
$links = array("brown" => array("/brown" => "Looking for the color brown?"));
```

I don't even know if I explained well enough, or if it's possible, but if it is, please let me know. Thanks!

Edit: I found one close to what I want, and got it to work somewhat. [Find the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009415/regex-to-match-words-or-phrases-in-string-but-not-match-if-part-of-a-url-or-insi). The problem is I can't limit the number of replacements, such as only do it once per page, or twice per page. Ideally I'd like to tell it to ignore it if it's in H tags. Hi milki_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match words or phrases in string but NOT match if part of a URL or inside <a> </a> tags. (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009415/regex-to-match-words-or-phrases-in-string-but-not-match-if-part-of-a-url-or-insi) or [Regular expression replace a word by a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276029/regular-expression-replace-a-word-by-a-link)

Comment: By the way, you can easily add a limit to the number of replacements to the answer you linked to, or any other `preg_replace`. See the `limit` argument at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Yes, I found the limit argument, that's why I deleted that from my original question. The difference between my question and any other one I can find here (and I've read about 15) is making sure it's not in a certain type of tag, such as blockquote, or H3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite HTML context-aware, then it's in fact *easier* to just resort to DOM functions. You'd still need the regex or string functions to rewrite the text nodes, so it would be way more code.

But a simple workaround to get the desired effect would be to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback). Simply match the *undesired* tags too, and then *ignore* them in the callback.

```
preg_replace_callback('%(<h)\d>.*?</h\d>|Amazon(?![^<]*</a>)%si',
                      'replace_cb_words', ...

function replace_cb_words($match) {

     // ignore the <h1>... matches
     if ($match[1]) return $match[0];

     // rewrite the words otherwise:
     return "<a ...>$match[0]</a>";
}
```